# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ service: string; }

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const [serviceList, setServiceList] = useState([{ service: '' }]);

const handleServiceChange = (e:any, index: any) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = { ...serviceList };
        list[index][name] = value;//getting the error here
        setServiceList(list);
    }
```

This error appears can anyone help me understand the issue and tell me how to solve this in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `name` can be anything, but elements in your list only have property `service`. So nothing can guarantee that `name` value is actually `"service"`. In general, you should try to avoid using `any` to type your variables.

Check the following code. I have used `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` as an example, but in your case in might be different. In any case, doing this makes typescript know that `name` is a string.

```typescript
const handleServiceChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) => {
  const {name, value} = e.target

  // NOTE the syntax to copy an array!!
  const list = [...serviceList];

  // TS knows that `name` is a string, but it can still be any string.
  // This ensures we only continue if `name === 'service'` and thus makes the error go away
  if (name !== 'service') return;

  list[index][name] = value; // Now we are sure that name == "service"
  setServiceList(list);
}
```